# A file was included when I pushed another file to my github repository - does not belong to that particular github repository

Tags: git, github

is there anyone can help me. I am new to git and github. I am organizing my files to its perspective repositories in my github account. I have 3 github repositories. I committed the file-1 (in which I have seen file-1 committed in the terminal in colored green) and pushed the file-1 to my github repository 1. By the way, I always use the git bash terminal. Then, I made a different file-2 having different content which is different to the first file I committed and pushed. So, when I committed the file-2 and pushed it to my other repository which it belongs to, the file-1 appears to that repository wherein file-1 does not belong to it. My question is, why is that happens? How can I fix it in which whenever I commit and push a file that I am working on, it should only be the files that is right and belonged to the intended repo. Please help me with it.

This was the steps I did.

First, I committed file-1 and pushed it to the right repository in my github where it belongs to. This is what I did.

```
git add file-1
git status
```

a reply from the terminal shows up here; then, I typed:

```
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Then, I changed the origin github-url to commit file-2 (different file/project). So, the git bash terminal showed me the file-2 as committed in which the font turned to color green. When I pushed it by typing the:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote
git remote -v
git remote add origin github-url
```

Then, the repo in my github account was changed to the correct repo I intended to push the file-2. I double checked if I have the right or correct repo in my github

```
git remote -v
```

And then, I committed the file-2. Like this:

```
git add file-2
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Git bash terminal replies that it succeeded in pushing it to the right/correct repository in my github. Then, I refreshed the browser. The file-2 appeared and the file-1 was included in which it does not belong to the repository of file-2. Please help me of what should I do to fix it.

Comment: A repository consists of all the files commited in it (plus their history and metadata and stuff). If you have two projects you need two repositories.

Comment: I have 3 repositories in my github account. I committed the first and pushed it to the correct repository in my github account. Then, I changed the origin or the repository url for my second file which is different to the first file I pushed. So, when I committed the file 2, git bash replied, it was committed. Then, when I pushed (file-2) to a different repository in my github wherein it belongs to, the file-1 was pushed as will to the wrong repository in which it was already pushed to my other repo in github.

Comment: After I pushed the file-1 to the correct repository from my github account. I changed the repo by typing

git remote remove "github-url"
git remote add origin "github-url 2"

Then, I commit the file-2 and pushed it to the selected repo. Upon refreshing the repo of the file-2 where it belong to, the file-1 was included even though, I did not include it in committing. How to fix my issue?

Comment: You're pushing the same local repo (your working directory) to different remotes.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The directory on your local machine where you did `git init` is a complete git repository. git commit acts on that repository. When you push, you push the whole repository.

Comment: So, for me to correct it. I need to make a new project directory for the file-2. Then, commit and push it to the correct repository in my github account, correct?

Comment: You mean, I need to create new project directory in my local repo for every project I am working on so that only those project files saved to that project directory will be committed and pushed to the intended github repository?

Comment: Not quite - you need separate local repos, with each one corresponding to one of your GitHub repos.

Comment: So you mean every folder of a project must be separated? For example: C:users/documents/Project-1

C:users/documents/Project-2

Is that what you mean?